# Run the cypress test in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-testing-library

i trying to configure github action, and i need to run the cypress test in incognito mode when I run it through a command in the terminal.

I try `npx cypress run --spec "path/to/your/test-file.js" --browser chrome --config chromeWebSecurity=false`, i try add this code in cypress config:

```
e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {},launchOptions) => {
        if (browser.family === 'chrome' && browser.name !== 'electron')
        launchOptions.args.push("--incognito");
        return launchOptions
      })
    }
```

But this helps me only when i run in with UI.

I also try `npx cypress run  --incognito "Path"` , but it end with  `error: unknown option: --incognito`

None of these options helped me run my test in incognito mode via a terminal command.